# why the tags on Google tag manager work only in the debbug-session (with google tag assistant)?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In fact, I have created tags on Google tag manager and they are well configured on Google analytics , I have tested them with Google tag assistant and everything is working properly.
But I found that no conversions or events are triggered and recorded on Google Analytics than those that were recorded during the test phase.

I concluded that the tags only work in the debbug-session (with google tag assistant) (is this true??!!)

Do you have any explanation, what is the origin of this problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you publish your changes in tag manager?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question, but do you have published your changes? Otherwise you're only testing in sandbox mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).